# Create table with multiple columns from a 2 columns table (rows to columns)

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following question that need your help to create Result table using data from the Resource table

I'm having a 'Resource' table:

| Code | Value |
| --- | --- |
| A | 100 |
| B | 100 |
| C | 220 |
| A | 150 |
| C | 300 |
| D | 120 |
| E | 120 |

Using SQL to create the 'Result' table:

| Code1 | Value1 | Code2 | Value2 | Code3 | Value3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 100 | B | 100 | C | 220 |
| A | 150 | C | 300 | D | 120 |
| E | 120 |  |  |  |  |

My idea is to create 3 tables then join them but I don't know how to get 1st, 2nd and 3rd lines. Does anyone has a more optimal way?

Thank you for reading my question!

Comment: Please explain the logic for the resource table.  It is not obvious.  Why does D --> B?  Why is E in the A column?

Comment: I have edited the table, sorry for mistyping. From what I understand, Result table will get 3 rows in Resource to put in Code1Value1, Code2Value2, …

Comment: Please mention your dbms with version.

Comment: I run it on sqliteonline.com

Comment: The rows of a table do not have inherent ordering. If you need specific ordering, please specify it. Otherwise the resulting table will have the rows in any [random] order.

Answer (score 1):

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table Resource (Code varchar(10),   Value int);

 insert into Resource values('A',   100);
 insert into Resource values('B',   100);
 insert into Resource values('C',   220);
 insert into Resource values('A',   150);
 insert into Resource values('C',   300);
 insert into Resource values('D',   120);
 insert into Resource values('E',   120);
```

Query#1:

```
 with cte as 
 (
 select *,row_number()over(order by null) rn from Resource
 )
 select (case when rn%3=1 then code end) as Code1, (case when rn%3=1 then value end) as Value1
 ,(case when rn%3=2 then code end) as Code2, (case when rn%3=2 then value end) as Value2,
 (case when rn%3=0 then code end) as Code3, (case when rn%3=0 then value end) as Value3
  from cte
```

Output:

| Code1 | Value1 | Code2 | Value2 | Code3 | Value3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 100 | null | null | null | null |
| null | null | B | 100 | null | null |
| null | null | null | null | C | 220 |
| A | 150 | null | null | null | null |
| null | null | C | 300 | null | null |
| null | null | null | null | D | 120 |
| E | 120 | null | null | null | null |

Query#2

```
 with cte as 
 (
 select *,row_number()over(order by null) rn from Resource
 )
 ,Code1 as 
  ( 
  select Code Code1, value  Value1
  , row_number()over(order by null) rownumber
  from cte n where rn%3=1
  )
 ,Code2 as
  ( 
  select Code Code2, value  Value2
  , row_number()over(order by null) rownumber
  from cte n where rn%3=2 
  )
 ,Code3 as
  ( 
  select Code Code3, value  Value3
  , row_number()over(order by null) rownumber
  
  from cte n where rn%3=0
  )
  
  select *,code1.rownumber from Code1 left join Code2 on Code1.rownumber=Code2.rownumber
  left join Code3 on Code2.rownumber = Code3.rownumber
```

| Code1 | Value1 | rownumber | Code2 | Value2 | rownumber | Code3 | Value3 | rownumber | rownumber |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 100 | 1 | B | 100 | 1 | C | 220 | 1 | 1 |
| A | 150 | 2 | C | 300 | 2 | D | 120 | 2 | 2 |
| E | 120 | 3 | null | null | null | null | null | null | 3 |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=9c48ca162c11a6c09a4b18a46ae7c01e)*

Comment: Please let me know if you face any more difficulties with this problem. It was a nice problem to work on.

Comment: If this answer helped you then please accept it

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify any ordering for the rows, so I sorted them by `(code, value)`. Remember the rows in a table do not have any inherent ordering (as they would have, for example, in a spreadsheet).

You can do:

```
with
x as (
  select *,
    (row_number() over(order by code, value) - 1) / 3 as line,
    (row_number() over(order by code, value) - 1) % 3 as col
  from t
)
select
  a.code as code1, a.value as value1,
  b.code as code2, b.value as value2,
  c.code as code3, c.value as value3
from x a
left join x b on b.line = a.line and b.col = 1
left join x c on c.line = a.line and c.col = 2
where a.col = 0;
```

Result:

```
 code1  value1  code2  value2  code3  value3 
 ------ ------- ------ ------- ------ ------ 
 A      100     A      150     B      100    
 C      220     C      300     D      120    
 E      120     null   null    null   null
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fpGs8wym31ZyB31jzTmnyV/0).